# ¿Cómo pasar referencias a los elementos de un diccionario en C#?

Tags: c#, diccionarios, referencias

¿Es posible pasar pasar referencias a los elementos de un diccionario?

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

```
//--------------------------------------------------
public class AnimationsNames
{
    public const string idle = "idle";
}
//--------------------------------------------------
public class AnimationChecker
{
    public static bool isFinished;
}
//--------------------------------------------------
public class AnimationsControler
{
    public static bool isIdle;

    public class Pair<T1, T2>
    {
        public T1 first;
        public T2 second;
        public Pair(ref T1 first, ref T2 second)
        {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Pair<bool,bool>> tirggerAnimations;
    
    public AnimationsControler()
    {
        tirggerAnimations = new Dictionary<string, Pair<bool, bool>>();

        tirggerAnimations.Add(AnimationsNames.idle, new Pair<bool, bool>(ref AnimationsChecker.isFinished, ref isIdle));

    }

    void CheckTriggerAnimations()
    {
        foreach(string key in tirggerAnimations.Keys)
        {
            if(tirggerAnimations[key].first && tirggerAnimations[key].second)
            {
                animator.SetTrigger(key);
            }
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------
```

Me gustaría poder pasar las referencias de las siguientes variables al diccionario:

AnimationsChecker.isFinished, isIdle

Ya que si solamente se me pasan los valores la función CheckTriggerAnimations() no funciona correctamente.

He intentado usar **ref** colocandolo en todos los sitios posibles pero no hay manera.

¿Alguna forma de poder hacer esto?
Gracias!!

Comment: Que error te da

Comment: No me da error. Simplemente no funciona... Es decir, las variables first y second siempre valen falso a pesar de que isFinished y isIdle sean true

Comment: Y idle coge bien su valor?

Comment: Si si... las variables isFinished y isIdle están perfectas

Comment: Ah!! perdón... si te referias a que si "key" toma el valor correcto "idle". Si, eso si funciona bien... lo único que falla es first y second.

Comment: En un diccionario siempre los objetos `Values` se almacenan por referencias, no necesitas hace lo siguiente public `Pair(ref T1 first, ref T2 second)` ten en cuenta que cuando haces eso, el valor por referencia solo tiene alcance dentro del ambito del procedimiento del constructor,  cuando ese procedimiento concluye, los valores almacenados `first` y `second` ya no son por referencia, son valores; pero cuando agregas un objeto `Pair` a tu diccionario, el diccionario lo que almacena es su referencia, si tomas el valor `Pair` y lo modificas, tambien cambiará en el diccionario.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, gracias por la explicación. Me quedó bien claro!! Anque creo que al final no lo voy a hacer así solo por legilibilidad. Creo que voy a sustituir el Pair por una función delegada que devuelva un bool.. asi me ahorraré declarar una variable tipo Pair y tener que actualizarla constantemente.Y podré usar las variables isFinished, y isIdle directamente. Lo que no tengo claro cual de las dos formas es mejor desde el punto de vista de la eficiencia. Pero bueno, lo que si es seguro es que de la segunda forma tendré que escribir menos :-) ... Graicas y Un Saludo!!